# LEFT JOIN not showing NULL results

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, isnull

I have 2 tables:

- DAY_INTERVALS (interval_start)
- ORDERS (client_id, order_time, order_total_price)

I want to display all the days in the DAY_INTERVAL table against the ORDERS table. Below is the SQL that I am using.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_time,'%Y-%m-%d') as dates, COALESCE(SUM(order_total_price), 0) AS  sales
FROM time_intervals ti 
LEFT  JOIN orders o 
ON DATE(o.order_time) = ti.interval_start  AND  (o.client_id = 157 or o.client_id is NULL)
GROUP BY DAY(o.order_time)
```

It is not displaying the NULL results of the days which don't exist in the orders table. The query should display all the days regardless if it is in the orders table.

I have looked at similar questions but the query above is what I come up with based on the other solutions.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove group by (and sum) and see whether you are getting expected result

Comment: Create a subquery for your select and then group

Comment: It was the group by causing the issue.

    SELECT interval_start, COALESCE( SUM( order_total_price ) , 0 ) AS sales
    FROM time_intervals ti
    LEFT JOIN orders o ON DATE( o.order_time ) = ti.interval_start
    AND (
    o.client_id =157
    OR o.client_id IS NULL
    )
    GROUP BY DAY( interval_start ) 

This worked

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of `AND  (o.client_id = 157 or o.client_id is NULL)` it would give you the data set you're looking for.

You're effectively executing the "Left Excluding JOIN" from this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

The only difference is you're executing it from your ON clause instead of the WHERE clause.

Comment: I removed the AND (o.client_id = 157 or o.client_id is NULL) however I need to filter by client_id

Comment: According to the link LEFT JOIN is what I want however it is not showing all the dates from time_intervals